# Diminuir horas php

Tags: php, laravel

Estou tendo problema para tratar a hora para diminuir ele em php.

Minha ideia pegar a hora que vem do banco de dados e diminuir com a hora atual e trazer o restante , porem n estou conseguindo.

codigo que estou usando como exemplo:

```
$results =DB::select("SELECT HoraCriacao FROM partidas WHERE (Aceitou=2) ORDER by Id desc LIMIT 1 ");
                foreach($results as $row){
                    $Hroin=$row->HoraCriacao;
                }
                $Hroin =  strtotime($Hroin);
                $Hroin=date('H:i:s',$Hroin);
                $Hroin=date_create($Hroin);
                $Horat= date('H:i:s');
                $Horat = explode(":", $Horat);
                date_sub($Hroin, date_interval_create_from_date_string($Horat[0].' hours'));
                date_sub($Hroin, date_interval_create_from_date_string($Horat[1].' minute'));
                date_sub($Hroin, date_interval_create_from_date_string($Horat[2].' second'));
                $Hroin=date_format($Hroin, 'H:i:s');
                $Hroin = explode(":", $Hroin);
                $banco=[
                    "mod" => "3",
                    "cron" => "$Hroin[0]:$Hroin[1]:$Hroin[2]"
                ];
                return response()->json($banco);
```

Comment: Amigo por favor tenta explicar melhor, porque está muito confuso o seu código e não consegui entender a sua necessidade.

Comment: No Banco de dados tem uma hora do evento de quando foi criado exemplo :
`$horain="14:40:00" ;` ai quero diminuir com a hora atual 
`$horaat="14:50:00";` ai quero pegar a diferença

Comment: Está usando Laravel? Esse `DB::select` é familiar

Comment: @KayoBruno, ai ele teria que voltar o resto tipo 00:10:00

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, sim estou sei bem pouco do laravel

Comment: Faltou colocar a tag então, hein

Comment: Coloquei abaixo uma resposta de como calcular a diferença entre datas. Vê se te ajuda em algo.

Comment: Cara, eu sempre procuro utilizar o https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ para manipulação de datas no Laravel

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Não consegui entender muito bem o que você quer, mas se está precisando calcular a diferença entre datas, você pode utilizar a classe *DateTime* do **PHP**.

```
<?php

$data_one = new DateTime( '2018-06-11 12:00:00' ); // Pode ser a data que vem do seu banco
$data_two = new DateTime(); // Se você não passar nenhum parâmetro, ele pega a data atual
$interval = $data_one->diff( $data_two ); // Calcula a diferença entre as duas datas

echo '<pre>';
print_r( $interval );
die;

# Retorno do print_r
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 2
    [d] => 8
    [h] => 21
    [i] => 50
    [s] => 20
    [weekday] => 0
    [weekday_behavior] => 0
    [first_last_day_of] => 0
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 69
    [special_type] => 0
    [special_amount] => 0
    [have_weekday_relative] => 0
    [have_special_relative] => 0
)
```

Com isso você tem a diferença entre as datas de ano, mês, dia, hora, minuto e segundo.